# Creación de archivo excel en java

Tags: java, excel

Estoy realizando un proyecto para generar un archivo de excel en java, ejecuto el archivo me corre me arroja un error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/math3/util/ArithmeticUtils
pero si me genera el archivo de excel pero cuando abro el archivo me aparece que esta dañado

```
public class CodigosReferencia 
{

     public static void main(String[] args) {
          crearExcel();
      }
 
     public static void crearExcel()
      {
           Workbook book = new HSSFWorkbook(); 
           Sheet sheet = book.createSheet("Hoja 1");

           try {
                   FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("Codigos.xls");
                   book.write(fileout); 
                   fileout.close();
               } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                       Logger.getLogger(CodigosReferencia.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
               } catch (IOException ex) {
                   Logger.getLogger(CodigosReferencia.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
          }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Hola! Parece que tienes un problema de dependencias... Para ayudar creo que vamos a necesitar algo mas de información ¿Como manejas las dependencias del proyecto? ¿Usas maven?  Parece que estás usando Apache POI, ¿Verdad? ¿Como agregaste los jars al proyecto?

Comment: Si estoy usando Apache POI, agregue los jar en la bibioteca del proyecto, agregue el poi.jav, poi.ooxml.jav, po.ooxml.schemas.jar, commons-collections.jar,xmlbeans.jar de la últimas versiones agregue todas esasporque también lo quiero para crear el archivo con la extensión .xlsx. No estoy usando Maven

Comment: Quizás tengas que agregar también commons-math3  pero no sabría decirte que versión. Quizás tengas que fijarte en la documentación de apache poi. Te recomiendo, en la medida que puedas claro, que utilices algún gestor de proyectos para no tener estos problemas.